# node_data_field not working on 6

Tags: entities

I have this structure:

```
<div class="FloatLeft RightText">: '.$data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_kampanya_adi_value.'</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="InfoTextItems">
    <div class="FloatLeft LeftText">Ajans</div>
    <div class="FloatLeft RightText">: '.$data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_ajans_value.'</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="InfoTextItems">
    <div class="FloatLeft LeftText">Reklamveren</div>
    <div class="FloatLeft RightText">: '.$data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_reklamveren_value.'</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="InfoTextItems">
    <div class="FloatLeft LeftText">Ödül</div>
    <div class="FloatLeft RightText">: '.$data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_odul_value.'</div>
```

It's working.
And 4 other field:

```
field_one
field_two
field_three
field_four
```

When I change this field to other, not working. Like this:

```
<div class="FloatLeft RightText">: '.$data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_one_value.'</div>
```

And not working on my page.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You should pay the users who have answered at least the courtesy of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're in the context of a views template. If so, you need to check that you have added the mentioned fields to the views config using the UI.
Are you using [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield)? If that's the case, check the field type that you're trying to render. The ending part is different for the different field types:

- text fields: _value
- files / images: _fid / _list / _data
- node / user references: _nid

So for example, if `field_one` is a file field, you could output the filepath by following the solution described here: https://drupal.org/node/1502064

Depending on the field type, you may need to prepare the variable in order to render it properly. Some problem descriptions and solutions can also be found in this thread: https://drupal.org/node/467190

Pay particular attention to these comments:

- https://drupal.org/comment/2276714#comment-2276714
- https://drupal.org/comment/3658192#comment-3658192
- https://drupal.org/comment/3929460#comment-3929460

To see what kind of information is accessible in your context, you can use several methods of examining the `$data` variable as Thomas4019 already mentioned. E.g.:

- `<?php print_r($data); ?>`
- `<?php var_dump($data); ?>`
- `<?php dpm($data); ?>` This requires the devel module being enabled

Answer (score 0):

I imagine $data->node_data_field_story_text_html_field_one_value is not being set.

Try running dpm($data) if you have the [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) enabled which will show you all the object members set.

Also you should check your php error logs and Drupal watchdog for any errors to see if they provide a clue as to why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing it as an anonymous user or user other  than super admin, then please check the permission of the fields and if you have set the value in the above said field or not.
May be the variable you are using to access the field value is not correct so check by printing $data variable.

```
   print_r($data);
```